# Why is it "wide *of* the mark" instead of "wide *off* the mark"?

Tags: phrases, prepositions

One says that something is "off the mark". For instance, an opinion or comment. But when it is way off, why is it "wide of the mark" instead of "wide off the mark"?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

"Wide of the mark" is an established phrase, using a meaning of "wide" that is rare today — notably still used in cricket, where a "wide" is a ball that was bowled outside the permitted target area (the wicket).

"Off the mark" is also established phrase.

"Wide off the mark" is not natural, because the relevant sense of "wide" is now used only absolutely ("went wide") or construed with "of". OED lists only "from" as an alternative, and marks it obsolete. I think it would be taken as an error for "wide of the mark". "Far off the mark" is more natural, but I don't recognise it as an established phrase.

[**Edited** to correct two points challenged in the comments: that "Off the mark" is an established phrase, and that the sense of "wide" is in wider(!) use than I said, though still restricted.]

Comment: For what it is worth, my Midwestern upbringing fully grasps "off the mark" without thinking about it. The typical usage would be "That was way off the mark." A similar phrasing: "This is way off base." Your milage may vary.

Comment: For what it's worth, that meaning of *wide* (off to side of a certain intended spot) is not particularly rare in the US.

Comment: In sports particularly, a missed soccer shot or field goal attempt is often described as having gone "wide left" or "wide right".  (but not "wide high".)

Comment: So would "widely off the mark" be more natural than "wide off the mark"?

Comment: I don't think so, @usernumber. _Wide_ in that sense is not very common, and _widely_ in that sense very rare.

Answer (score 9):

"Wide off the mark" is incorrect and I would say that is because wide doesn't tell you about *distance* (like "far" does), it tells you about *size*. After all, you can't say "big off the mark" either, can you?

When you say "wide of the mark" you are using "wide" to mean not "of a great size from side-to-side" but "to the side of". Incidentally I don't think you should take it to mean that it is far off target: even a near-miss is wide of the mark, so the sense is not quite the same as "far off the mark".

"Wide of" is used quite frequently in this way: for instance, footballers are forever hitting shots wide of the goal. (That's round-ball football by the way, not the American sort...) There is also the specific cricket-specific sense of "wide" which Colin Fine has mentioned, which seems to have the same sense of "to the side", but in that context has even got to the point where you can talk about "a wide", making it into a noun.

Answer (score 0):

here's [one possible explanation](http://www.englishforums.com/English/WideOffOfTheMark/lwrkn/post.htm)

> They both work.  I think "of" is more
>   common.  It's like "clear of the
>   mark."
>
> "Off" would be more like "far off the
>   mark."
>
> Grammatically, I think "wide of the
>   mark" is adverbial, as in "I placed it
>   west of the mark."
>
> "Wide" answers the question "where,"
>   and the prepositional phrase "of the
>   mark" modifies "wide."
>
> With "wide off the mark,"  I think the
>   prepositional phrase answers the
>   question "where," and "wide" is
>   adjectival, modifying the
>   prepositional phrase.

Comment: Thanks, pageman. If "far off the mark" would be correct, I fail to see why "wide off the mark" is different. One can say "way off the mark" and not "way of the mark". Why is _wide_ any different? Maybe , my brain just cannot click to the "<adjective> of the mark" as being correct. I do know that "wide of the mark" is the correct accepted usage but just cannot understand why that is so.

Comment: @Raju English is like that - probably the same way that the opposite of "stand down" IS NOT "stand up" :)

Comment: @pageman: There are corners of the English language where logic holds no sway. Accepted. This, I would have thought, could be explained by an existing grammar rule. But, if it doesn't, that would explain why people (me included) trip on it. Thanks!

Comment: @Raju -- see my answer - are you still unclear about why "far off the mark" can be right while "wide off the mark" isn't? I think this is actually quite logical.

Comment: @Raju a lot of it becomes easier by usage - believe me, there are phrases that I've been using since I was a child that I now have to look up :)

Comment: @pageman: it does become easier with increased usage but that does not mean that it is correct. It becomes correct after sufficient time has passed and the old form that was once deemed correct is no longer there with a wagging finger. There are several things that our teachers that used to warn us about that have become common. I find it hard to use, though; I have the mental picture of my teacher with arms akimbo waiting for me to make that mistake. Old habits die hard, I guess.

Comment: @Raju English doesn't evolve homoegenously over all areas at the same rate; what makes sense in your region might be strange in another - the "correctness" you are aiming for is what prescriptive vs. descriptive views are all about :)